# Export fitted values from time series regression in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, ndvi, regression

I have used harmonic regression to model NDVI values in GEE. Now I would like to export fitted values for every half-month timestep. Unfortunately, much of the exported cells rasters have 'nodata', even though I can visuallize the fitted values.

How can I export fitted values?

https://code.earthengine.google.com/b9de09ca968e2c5f31cc30308ac80f46

```
//This field contains UNIX time in milliseconds
var timeField = 'system:time_start'

// ----------------- Input user-required info ---------------------------
// Dates should be within Landsat TM range (Aug 22, 1982 to present)
var startdate = ee.Date('2011-01-01');
var enddate = ee.Date('2011-12-31');
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Define AOI 
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
var aoi = ee.Feature(roi);

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Load Landsat imagery 
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

// Define Landsat surface reflectance bands
var sensor_band_dict = ee.Dictionary({
                        l8 : ee.List([1,2,3,4,5,6,10]),
                        l7 : ee.List([0,1,2,3,4,6,9]),
                        l5 : ee.List([0,1,2,3,4,6,9]),
                        l4 : ee.List([0,1,2,3,4,6,9])  
                        });
// Sensor band names corresponding to selected band numbers                        
var bandNames = ee.List(['blue','green','red','nir','swir1','swir2','pixel_qa']);

// ------------------------------------------------------
// Landsat 4 - Data availability Aug 22, 1982 - Dec 14, 1993
var ls4 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT04/C01/T1_SR')
              .filterBounds(aoi.geometry().bounds())
              .select(sensor_band_dict.get('l4'), bandNames); 

// ------------------------------------------------------
// Landsat 5 - Data availability Jan 1, 1984 - May 5, 2012
var ls5 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR')
              .filterBounds(aoi.geometry().bounds())
              .select(sensor_band_dict.get('l5'), bandNames); 

// Landsat 7 data are only used during operational SLC and
// to fill the gap between the end of LS5 and the beginning
// of LS8 data collection

// Prior to SLC-off            
// -------------------------------------------------------
// Landsat 7 - Data availability Jan 1, 1999 - Aug 9, 2016
// SLC-off after 31 May 2003
var ls7 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR') 
              .filterDate('1999-01-01', '2003-05-31') 
             .filterBounds(aoi.geometry().bounds())
              .select(sensor_band_dict.get('l7'), bandNames);

// Post SLC-off; fill the LS 5 gap
// -------------------------------------------------------
// Landsat 7 - Data availability Jan 1, 1999 - Aug 9, 2016
// SLC-off after 31 May 2003
var ls7_2 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR') 
              .filterDate('2012-05-05', '2014-04-11') 
              .filterBounds(aoi.geometry().bounds())
              .select(sensor_band_dict.get('l7'), bandNames);

// --------------------------------------------------------
// Landsat 8 - Data availability Apr 11, 2014 - present
var ls8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')  
              .filterBounds(aoi.geometry().bounds())
              .select(sensor_band_dict.get('l8'), bandNames);

// Merge landsat collections
var l4578 = ee.ImageCollection(ls4
              .merge(ls5)
              .merge(ls7)
              .merge(ls7_2)
              .merge(ls8).sort('system:time_start'))
              .filterDate(startdate, enddate);

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Mask clouds, cloud shadows, and snow
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// https://landsat.usgs.gov/sites/default/files/documents/ledaps_product_guide.pdf
function maskClouds(img) {
  var qa = img.select(['pixel_qa']);
  var clouds = qa.bitwiseAnd(8).neq(0).or // Cloud shadow (0 = clear, 1 = contamination)
              (qa.bitwiseAnd(16).neq(0)).or // Snow
              (qa.bitwiseAnd(32).neq(0)); // Cloud
  return img.addBands(clouds.rename('clouds')); // Add band of contaminated pixels
}

// Apply mask
var img_masked = l4578.map(maskClouds);

//function to add variables for NDVI, MNDWI, MBSRV, MBSRN, AWESH, time and a constant to imagery

var addVariables = function(image) {
  //compute time in fractional years since the epoch
  var date = ee.Date(image.get(timeField));
  var years = date.difference(ee.Date('1970-01-01'), 'year');
  //return image with added bands
  return image
    //add a time band
  .addBands(ee.Image(years).rename('t'))
  .float()
  //add constant band
  .addBands(ee.Image.constant(1))
  //add NDVI band
  .addBands(image.normalizedDifference(['nir', 'red']).rename('NDVI')).toFloat()
};


var filteredLandsat = img_masked
  .filterBounds(roi)
  .map(addVariables);
print(filteredLandsat)

// ------------------------------------------------------
// NDVI
// ------------------------------------------------------

//LINEAR MODELLING OF TIME USING ORDINARY LEAST SQUARES

//list of the independent variable names
var independents = ee.List(['constant', 't']);

//name of the dependent variable
var dependent = ee.String('NDVI');

//Compute a linear trend. This will have two bands: 'residuals' and a
// 2x1 band called 'coefficients' (columns are for dependent variables).
var trend = filteredLandsat.select(independents.add(dependent))
.reduce(ee.Reducer.linearRegression(independents.length(), 1));

//Map.addLayer(trend, {}, 'trend array image');

//flatten the coefficients into a 2-band image
var coefficients = trend.select('coefficients')
.arrayProject([0])
.arrayFlatten([independents]);


//ESTIMATE SEASONALITY WITH A HARMONIC MODEL

//use these independent variables in the harmonic regression
var harmonicIndependents = ee.List(['constant', 't', 'cos', 'sin']);

//add harmonic terms as new image bands
var harmonicLandsat = filteredLandsat.map(function(image) {
  var timeRadians = image.select('t').multiply(2 * Math.PI);
  return image
  .addBands(timeRadians.cos().rename('cos'))
  .addBands(timeRadians.sin().rename('sin'));
});

var harmonicTrend = harmonicLandsat
  .select(harmonicIndependents.add(dependent))
  //the output of this reducer is a 4x1 array image.
  .reduce(ee.Reducer.linearRegression({
    numX: harmonicIndependents.length(),
    numY: 1
  }));

//Turn the array image into a multi-band image of coefficients
var harmonicTrendCoefficients = harmonicTrend.select('coefficients')
  .arrayProject([0])
  .arrayFlatten([harmonicIndependents]);

// Compute fitted values
var fittedHarmonic = harmonicLandsat.map(function(image) {
  return image.addBands(
    image.select(harmonicIndependents)
      .multiply(harmonicTrendCoefficients)
      .reduce('sum')
      .rename('fitted_ndvi').float());
});



// CREATE NEW COLLECTION WITH SELECTED BANDS AND INDICES

var img_indices = ee.ImageCollection(fittedHarmonic.select('fitted_ndvi'));

// rename bands

function renameBands(image) {
  var bands = ['fitted_ndvi'];
  var new_bands = ['ndvi'];
  return image.select(bands).rename(new_bands);
}

var img_indices = img_indices.map(renameBands)



// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Calculate hillshade mask
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
function addHillshade(img) {
    var solar_azimuth = img.get('SOLAR_AZIMUTH_ANGLE');
    var solar_zenith = img.get('SOLAR_ZENITH_ANGLE'); // solar altitude = 90-zenith
    var solar_altitude = ee.Number(90).subtract(ee.Number(solar_zenith));
   return img.addBands(ee.Terrain.hillshade(dem, solar_azimuth, solar_altitude).rename('hillshade').float()); 
}

// Add hillshade bands
var img_indices = img_indices.map(addHillshade);
print(img_indices)



// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Produce NDVI mosaic for second half of April
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
var mosaicstart = ee.Date('2011-04-16');
var mosaicend = ee.Date('2011-04-30');
var ndvi_mosaic = img_indices.select('ndvi').filterDate(mosaicstart,mosaicend).mosaic().clip(aoi);

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Visualization of NDVI Image Products
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

// Center on polgon
Map.centerObject(geometry2, 15);


// Viz parameters: classes: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
var ndvi_viz = {min:-1, max: 1, palette: ['000000', '002ba1', '6287ec', '77b800', 'c1bdb6']};
var ls_viz =  {bands: [ 'red', 'green', 'blue'], min:0, max:3000, gamma: [0.95, 1.1, 1]};

var landsatMosaic = filteredLandsat.filterDate(mosaicstart, mosaicend).mosaic()

Map.addLayer(landsatMosaic, ls_viz, 'Landsat')
// DSWE
Map.addLayer(ndvi_mosaic, ndvi_viz, 'ndvi mosaic', true);

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Export image
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

// Using crs and crsTransform rather than scale is recommended for aligning Landsat pixels <-- having trouble with this
  Export.image.toDrive({
    image: ndvi_mosaic, 
    description: '2011Apr2',
    folder: 'NDVI_regressed',
    scale: 30,
    //crs: 'EPSG:5070',  // 5070 = USGS Albers Equal Area Conic
    //crsTransform: [30, 0, -2214330, 0, -30, 2091360], // 5070-specific transform
    maxPixels: 1e13,
    region: aoi  //for complex areas: aoi.geometry().bounds(),
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have Landsat imagery for the whole AOI in your date-range. One strategy to deal with this is to pick imagery closest to the date-range, so you always get something.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/78ef55285a8cca89a9ab983c978d3442

```
var mosaicstart = ee.Date('2011-04-16');
var mosaicend = ee.Date('2011-04-30');

var mosaicdays = mosaicend.difference(mosaicstart, 'day');
var mosaicmiddle = mosaicstart.advance(mosaicdays.divide(2), 'day');

function addQualityBand(image) {
  var distance = mosaicmiddle.difference(image.date(), 'day').abs();
  var quality = ee.Image(distance)
    .multiply(-1)
    .int()
    .rename('quality');
  return image.addBands(quality);
}

var ndvi_mosaic = img_indices
  .map(addQualityBand)
  .qualityMosaic('quality') // Pick pixels closest to the middle of the date range
  .select('ndvi')
  .clip(aoi);
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked! I am trying to do the same for DSWE (dynamic surface water extent), which has 5 indices including NDVI. The values of the indices determine the DSWE class. I am having the same problem of masking when no Landsat imagery. I tried adding your snippet, but it did not work. Can you provide advice?

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/0209c0a291caacc632cefe0098889026

Comment: I don't see any problems with that script. Your DSWE layer got values for the whole AOI, as far as I can tell.

Comment: For some reason, in the DSWE script, the region of the raster that should be NA (like the NDVI script) is coming in as zeros. I can't figure that part out either.  I REALLY appreciate your help so far